# is it possible to add AOP functions .before .after to kendo grid functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

is it possible
 to add .before(function){}) .after(function(){}) hook to kendo grid functions.

such as e.g before refresh grid, after refresh grid:

```
$('#GridName').data('kendoGrid').refresh(); // built-in
```

=>

```
$('#GridName').data('kendoGrid').beforeRefresh(function(){
  //todo
});

$('#GridName').data('kendoGrid').afterRefresh(function(){
  //todo
});
```

Comment: What moment are you trying to capture? Did you try placing your events handlers on the `dataBinding` and `dataBound` events of the Kendo Grid?

Comment: Try [this](http://dojo.telerik.com/AbOPur) demo. I've added a button before the grid which refreshes it. You can see the two events I mentioned running one after the other.